# How can I determine if a RECT area inside of my window is covered by other windows (occluded) using windows APIs?

Tags: c++, windows, api, visual-c++, windows-api-code-pack

How can I determine if a RECT area inside of my window is covered by other windows (occluded). I mean, if the user can see this RECT area or not?

I could not find the right answer to this question. In fact, I should define a function with a signature like this

```
 bool isWindowPartVisible(HWND handle, RECT rect)
```

Inside this function, I am allowed to use only the Windows API function.

Comment: What context are you trying to determine this (is it during a WM_PAINT message)? Why do you need to determine this? (There may be a better way to achieve that, or it may be unnecessary.) [Edit] the question to include additional details. (Even if you determine if a part is visible, the user can move, expand, or make other UI changes that changes what part of your window is visible.)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [WindowFromPoint()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-windowfrompoint) for sufficient number of points in that `rect` and check if it's YOUR window.